# Drop down lists not populating in DB in Django Forms on click of submit button

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have a table inside form. It looks like below:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Title{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<form actions="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    <table border = "1" cellpadding = "10" cellspacing = "10" bordercolor = "green">
    <tr>
        <th>numbers</th>
        <th>Extension</th>
        <th>Vendor</th>
    </tr>
        {% for number in numbers %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ number }}</td>
        <td class = "select">Select Extension
        <select name="extensions">
            {% for obj in sipextensionsets %}
            <option value={{obj.sip_extension}}>{{ obj.sip_extension }}</option>
            {%  endfor %}
        </select>
        </td>

        <td>vendor</td>
    </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>

<input type="submit" value="save"/>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

My forms.py is below:

```
from django import forms

from .models import column

class didsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = column
        fields = ('extension')
```

My views.py is below

```
def saveintodb(request):
    try:
       instance = coloumn.objects.get(pk=1)
    except:
        instance = coloumn(pk=1)
        instance.save()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dids_form = didsForm(data=request.POST['extensions'], instance=instance)
        if dids_form.is_valid():
            dids_form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Settings updated. Please apply settings.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Error: Invalid settings.")
    else:
        dids_form = didsForm(instance=instance)

    return render(request, 'dids/index.html', {'dids_form': dids_form})
```

In the table, there is a drop down (select tag). I want to save the data into database when user selects something from dropdown and clicks on save button. I know I have mistaken somewhere in views.

Comment: In htm you named field extensions but in forms.py extension. Check which is correct.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner In forms.py, it is the column name of the model. In html, it is name attribute of select tag. So both are correct and independent of each other.

Comment: Also, `fields` needs to be a tuple in `forms.py`. Add a coma after, like `fields = ('extension',)`

Comment: @zaidfazil I tried this just now and it does not change anything. DB is still not populated

Comment: Have you debugged? what comes inside `request.POST['extensions']` when you save the data?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a few things wrong here, unfortunately.

The main problem is that you're passing `request.POST['extensions']` as the `data` argument to your form on POST; but that argument is expecting the whole POST, not a single field.

Linked to that is that you have not used the same name for the field in the model and the field in the form. Although you say in your comment that this is intentional, there doesn't seem to be a reason for it, and it's breaking things. Give them the same name.

Thirdly, you aren't letting Django populate the form, or show any errors when it's not valid. You shouldn't be explicitly passing `sipextenionset` (although you actually don't seem to be passing that at all, so I'm not sure where it's coming from), and you certainly shouldn't be explicitly iterating. You should let Django display the field:

```
   <td>{{ number }}</td>
   <td class="select"><label for="id_extension">Select Extension</label>
   {{ form.extension }}
    </td>
```

Finally, I can't at all understand what you are doing with that outer for loop through `numbers`; you will end up with several values for `extension`, which is not expected by your form, your model, or your view.

Comment: There are a lot of extensions out of which I need to map one extension to numbers and then update the DB. That's why extensions are in drop down so that user can select "one of many extensions". What I need is that once user selects the extension and clicks on save button, it should update the DB.  The sipextpensionsets in coming from views.py where I am querying the DB using django ORM. I have not pasted that part of code here, do you want me to?  I did not get your request.POST part since I am quite new to Django so I would greatly appreciate if you can explain a but more.